# Column to row translation using sed

Tags: ruby, bash, csv, filter, sed

I'm writing a `bash` script to get data from procmail and produce an output CSV file.

At the end, I need to translate from this:

```
---label1: 123456
---label2: 654321
---label3: 246810
---label4: 135791
---label5: 101010
```

to this:

```
label1,label2,label3,label4,label5
123456,654321,246810,135791,101010
```

I could do this easily with a `ruby` script but I don't want to call another script other than the `bash` script. So I've though of doing it with `sed`.

I can extract the data I want like this:

```
sed -nr 's/^---(\S+): (\S+)$/\1,\2/p'
```

But I don't know how to transpose it. Can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand your reason for not using Ruby.  You want to avoid using a scripting language, and therefore, you use two.  Your script is going to grow and grow, and before you know it, there will be for loops and tr and awk and sed calls all over the place.
And using a proper CSV library may help as well, if not now, then on the next job where there are quotes or commas in your data.
I don't know about Ruby, but Perl has one.

Comment: The thing is that I didn't want a different file, just one bash script to do the processing. But I found a way to use ruby as a oneliner in the bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved it using ruby, as suggested buy Dave Webb but as a one-liner not a here document with the following script:

```
ruby -ne 'BEGIN{@head=[];@data=[]}; @head << $1 && @data << $2 if $_.match(/^---(\S+): (\S+)$/); END{puts @head.join(",");puts @data.join(",")}' $FILE
```

I didn't know that I could use BEGIN, END blocks to set the variables and output the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running `sed` I'd argue that you *are* calling another script.  So why not write it in Ruby if that's easier to write and maintain?

If you're worried about having multiple files could embed the Ruby code in the bash script as a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) (assuming Ruby can read a script from the Standard Input).

Comment: ruby can read the script from standard input as a here document but I then lose the standard input as data and have to mess with opening files. See my answer to see my final solution as a ruby one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

you can just do everything in awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{
    FS=": "
}
{ 
  gsub("---","")
  label[++c] = $1
  num[++d] =$2
}
END{
    for(i=1;i<c;i++){
        printf label[i]","
    }
    print label[c]
    for(i=1;i<d;i++){
        printf num[i]","
    }
    print num[d]    
}' file
```

output

```
# ./test.sh
label1,label2,label3,label4,label5
123456,654321,246810,135791,101010
```

redirect the output to csv file as needed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?
(from [unix.com](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/18897-row-column-transpose.html#post80189))

```
num=$(awk -F"," 'NR==1 { print NF }' data)
print $num

i=1
while (( $i > tmpdata
(( i = i + 1 ))
done
mv tmpdata data
```

Answer (score 0):

you said you needed bash script..

```
#!/bin/bash
labels=`awk '/---/{printf("%s,",$1)}' file.txt `
values=`awk '/---/{printf("%s,",$2)}' file.txt `
labels=`echo $labels|sed 's/---//g;s/\://g;s/\,$//'`
values=`echo $values|sed 's/\,$//`
echo $labels
echo $values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this from within the shell script:

cat demo | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | sed -e s/'---'// | tr '\n' ',' > csv_file

cat demo | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ',' >> csv_file

Comment: there is no need for cat. pass the file to awk